# How to build war from maven nonstandard structure project?

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

I work on a project with some directory structure in my company. Now I have to convert project to Maven project. It's web app based on companies framework.
Project is exported to war file,

Here is structure of project:

```
web-app-name
    - WebContent
        - css
        - html
        - images
        - modules
        - WEB-INF
           - classes
           - config
           - data
           - lib
           - src
              - src_core
              - src_util
              - ... other src_
              - propertis.file
```

I can't use standard Maven structure.
So far I build pom.xml file and make project to work.
Dependencies are downloaded from private server and that works fine.

Problem is file structure. I try to override default maven paths, but no go.
When i export war file there is no css, html, images files ... There is just WEB-INF directory:

```
WEB-INF
  - classes
  - lib
META-INF
```

Is there a way to get all directories in war file that are under WebContent with some exceptions, or I can forget to convert project to Maven?

Pom file without dependencies:

```
...
<properties>
  <dborr.base.dir>${basedir}</dborr.base.dir>
</properties>
<build>
  <sourceDirectory>${dborr.base.dir}\coll_dborr\WebContent</sourceDirectory>
      <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
      <compilerVersion>1.7</compilerVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
         <warSourceDirectory>${dborr.base.dir}/coll_dborr/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
       <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${dborr.base.dir}/coll_dborr/WebContent/css</directory>
          </resource>
       </webResources>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Another question is there a way to include all source files to .classpath from pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should work, see [Apache Maven WAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory):

> **warSourceDirectory:**
>
> Single directory for extra files to include in the WAR. This is where you place your JSP files.
>
> **- Type**: java.io.File
>
> **- Required**: Yes
>
> **- Default**: ${basedir}/src/main/webapp

But your path `${dborr.base.dir}\coll_dborr\WebContent`is not right, it should be `${basedir}\web-app-name\WebContent`.

Your `sourceDirectory` seems also not right, because it has to be the path to your sources not to your webapp resources.

Maybe you have also to remove `webResources`, because its already included in `warSourceDirectory`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that i use internal server for download dependencies, so plugins do not work?  <br/><mirrors>
 <mirror>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>url-to-server</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>